# How to switch Emacs windows from vertical split to horizontal split?

Tags: emacs

Suppose I have two windows open in Emacs:

```
Window A

..............

Window B
```

Is there a way to switch to

```
         :
         :
Window A : Window B
         :
         :
```

(horizontal split to vertical split)

Is there a way to switch view without close windows?

Comment: Note that there is a new emacs.stackexchange.com. You could reasonably ask this question there.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know this. I will post questions to emacs.stack from now on.

Comment: If you do choose to ask on [emacs.se] instead, please make sure you delete this question first to avoid cross posting.

Comment: Yes, good point. I'll do it as soon as I get back to my computer. (I'm reading from mobile phone now.)

Comment: @terdon I tried to delete this question; however, it has answers, it cannot be deleted.

Comment: No worries, I closed it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First split one of the windows in two 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd>, 
then switch one of the two horizontal windows to the previous one (i.e. the other horizontal split): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Finally navigate to the other split window: 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> followed by another <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> and close <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>

If you have to do this often, you might want to look at the [ToggleWindowSplit](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ToggleWindowSplit) package

Comment: Thank you. But I don't mean to switch focus, (as you can see from the demo-picture)I want to switch from horizontal split view to vertical split view.

Comment: @nick sorry had not understood that that is what you wanted, had read `||` as `or`. Updated the picture.